# How to integrate my PHP Form to a Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Well, i have a little script created by a guy from a project where i work. It's a Form that connects to Database and is basicly a User Writer. So when you fill all the fields, the script sends that info to the VPS Database and it makes a basic Account Creation .

My question is: How i can do that or if someone can give me a hand. Since im not a Programmer this kind of things (pretty much the only thing so far i tried) is hard to understand (atleast for me.)

I leave a Pastebin so you can see on what my php file looks like.

http://pastebin.com/MCRBGj1N

Feel free to use it if you want. (The native language of the file is Spanish, feel free to ask if you dont understand something.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My first advise to you would be , please do not use md5 to salt your passwords. It would take all but 0.25 seconds to get the plain password from that. Try sha1 or something similar.

Second, I would ask you as a beginner, to not try something as complex as this. Alternatively, use something that is already out there, and tweak it for your own use.

If you've gotten as far as the above, and are simply looking to make some forms, with the login and other things already setup for you, try some of the groupwares written in php. egroupware, heck even some joomla components have form writers for free.

My advice is to see how others do it first, learn little techniques along the way, and then try something as 'core application' as this.

In fact, if you're looking to make your own forms with *minimal* programming background and have access to a linux box, try simple groupware. I am pretty sure it won't take you more than a few hours to get the server up, and your first form done.

Promise.

Comment: its actually common knowledge....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774345/md5-security-is-fine   But MD5 is considered "broken" by security professionals.  www.cmd5.org     thanks for the -1

Comment: This has been taken from internet. As far as i go, i allways been trying to understand part of the code, even im currently studying HTML5 and CSS coding. I can make pretty well the stylesheets and all that stuff. But the only thing that's actually stoping me from completing my Project (It's a Game Server connected to a Win Server 2003 VPS where there's a Database connected to the forum to allow users from the gameserver to register on our database to being unlock the Play abilitie.) I will take part of what you say and get to work a few hours on something or atleast to try.

Thanks

Comment: since you're using wordpress, this may be useful, plus press the up arrow if you found my answer useful    http://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/

Comment: The -1 wasn't for your comment on md5. It was for answering a question about Wordpress forms with a rambling answer about Joomla and groupware. If you edit that out I'll happily get rid of the minus vote - using a plugin is good advice here imo, although I would have said Gravity forms.