# PHP Insert Table Data Code not Inserting Data into MSSQL Table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a PHP page that should insert a username and password into my MSSQL table "users". When I run the page the only thing that appears is the errors:

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: 'md5' is not a recognized built-in function name. (severity 15) in D:\Hostins0\html\insertadminaccount.php on line 10

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in D:\Hostinstml\insertadminaccount.php on line 10
'md5' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Here is my full PHP page code:

```
<?php
$conn=mssql_connect('sm','Gaer','Ra1!');
mssql_select_db('Gser',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
   $sqla = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES ('rob_dewar01', " . md5 ('KingDozer') . ")";
mssql_query($sqla, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());

if (!mssql_query) {
    // The query has failed, print a nice error message
    // using mssql_get_last_message()
    die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Comment: The error message (`'md5' is not a recognized built-in function name`) tells you *exactly* what the problem is. What are you really asking about here?

Comment: Did you even TRY reading the error message? This has NOTHING to do with PHP. You're generating invalid sql, e.g. there is **NO** md5() function in MSSQL.

Comment: Reading is not good! Make a SO question instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSSQL doesn't have a direct `md5` function (you can convert it as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525997/generate-md5-hash-string-with-t-sql)). You need to use it through PHP like so:

```
$sqla = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES ('rob_dewar01', '" . md5('KingDozer') . "')";
```

Also, [`md5` is not secure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774345/md5-security-is-fine) Look into using prepared statements.

See the [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords#answer-401684) question for more information about hashing passwords in PHP.

Comment: +1 for linking that md5 is not the way to go.

Comment: I tried that, and I now get the errors `Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near 'b1a1953c219343f3313f0feae9abbe8'. (severity 15) in D:\Hostinga0\html\insertadminaccount.php on line 10

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in D:\Hosting\ahtml\insertadminaccount.php on line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'b1a1953c219343f3313f0feae9abbe8'.`

Comment: add quotes around `. md5('KingDozer')`

Comment: Edited the code in my question to what I currently have on my PHP page. I do have the quotes around `. md5('KingDozer')` and it is reading the errors I commented above.

Comment: @Michael See my edit with the single quotes. If you were using prepared statements you wouldn't have this mess.

Comment: Thank you @FreshPrinceOfSO. The code works now.