# MSSQL PHP Authentication System is not Logging in

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a MSSQL table named users with the username `rob_dewar01` and the password `0b1a1953c219343f3313f0feae9abbe8`. The password was put into the table as MD5 using PHP code and translates to `KingDozer` without MD5. There is a page called login.php that has a form with two inputs where the user may input the username and password. The login.php will send to the check.php page when the user hits submit. The check.php should then check if the username and password is correct, then send the user to the management page. If the username and password is incorrect, the check.php page will send the user back to the login.php page. My problem is when I try to correctly input the username `rob_dewar01` and the password `KingDozer` into the login.php page and hit submit, it sends me right back to the login.php page. I am not sure if this is happening because it is being used with MSSQL or PHP.

Here is the login.php page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Login to === Back-end</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="check.php">
      Username:<br />
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <br /><br />
      Password:<br />
      <input type="password" name="password" />
      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" id="subbut" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is all my PHP code for check.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$conn=mssql_connect('gsom','Gser','Ros1!');
mssql_select_db('GBsr',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    $result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND
      password=md5('$password')");
  if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = 1;
    }
  }

  if(!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {
    header("location:login.php");
  } else {
    header("location:careers/managecareers.php");
  }
?>
```

Here is the PHP page's code I used to insert a username and password into the MSSQL table users:

```
<?php
$conn=mssql_connect('gbscom','GBser','Robs!');
mssql_select_db('Gser',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

mssql_query($conn,"INSERT INTO Users (username, password)
VALUES ('rob_dewar01', md5('KingDozer'))");


if (!mssql_query) {
    // The query has failed, print a nice error message
    // using mssql_get_last_message()
    die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Not a good idea to show your user and password to the world

Comment: I plan to make a new username and password once I get this working.

Comment: Isn't this the same problem [you had before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788923/php-insert-table-data-code-not-inserting-data-into-mssql-table) where `MD5()` is not natively available to MSSQL?

Comment: You need to do some error checking on your query.  `if (!$result) { echo mssql_get_last_message(); exit(); }` to abort before your redirection and see what has gone wrong.

Comment: Not sure if anyone has advised in your previous questions yet, but your code is now vulnerable to SQL injection, since `$username` is unfiltered input.  [PHP's MSSQL doesn't have good support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php) for escaping, but anyway [read this question thoroughly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I am unsure that $username is vulnerable to SQL injection because it is not an "insert into table" kind of form. I believe it is rather just a query of the table's data. @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: It _is_ vulnerable. If for example `$username == "' OR 1=1 --"` it will return all users regardless of password and your check `mssql_num_rows($result) > 0` will succeed. SQL injection isn't only an issue for INSERT/UPDATE; it applies everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with @MichaelBerkowski comments. You should hash the password with PHP.

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

See [here](https://www.php.net/md5) for more details. Or better yet use a different hashing algorithm that hasn't been compromised and consider adding a salt to your hashed passwords and sanitizing your inputs.