# How to deal with different sized char variables?

Tags: c, char

I am trying to implement a straightforward code which return the respective MD5 for a given password:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Returns the MD5 hash for a given password
char hash_password(char password){

    FILE *fp;
    char command [1024];
    sprintf(command, "md5 <<< '%c'", password);

    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    }

    char hashed[1024];
    fgets(hashed , 1024 , fp);
    pclose(fp);
    return hashed;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char hashed = hash_password("password");
    printf("%s\n", hashed);
    return 0;
}
```

My issues are the following:

1. I get a warning at `return hashed;` saying: "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning char[1024] from a function with result type char"
2. I get a warning at `char hashed = hash_password("password");` saying: "Incompatible pointer to integer passing char[9] to a parameter of type char"
3. The program returns `\320` which is not the correct hash result.

My two days of experience with C says the function will never return what I need since `hashed` will die with the end of the function, right? How can I get it fixed?

Comment: 1. Do not return variables that are on the stack for a function. 2. Get the data types right - the compiler should pick this up

Comment: Note: MD5 is deprecated as unsafe.

Comment: You should check this out: http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers-arrays

Comment: `char` means a single char. `char x[1024];` means an array of 1024 chars.

Comment: @Olaf - What do you suggest?

Comment: That was just a note you should remember and tell your teacher. If this is just some homework, leave it at that. Otherwise you should take it serious. bcrypt is still deemed safe. Or you use a sha2 hash (but there are also weaknesses, but the longer ones should be safe. However, you should do some research on your own if interested; this cannot be explained in few words.

Comment: @Olaf Where is the source of your statement?

Comment: @marko: Here is **one** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774345/md5-security-is-fine/6774381#6774381

Comment: It is a best practice to quote a reliable source.

Comment: `char hash_password(char password)` What? A single char password? It'll be guessed in nanoseconds. And then you passed into it a full string `hash_password("password");`

Comment: If you're using MD5 for security in any form, switch immediately to something more secure such as PBKDF2 or bcrypt. As for sources, you can find one [here](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068) and another [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6151#section-2). The first link contains several links to references itself, including advisories from Microsoft and VeriSign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot return a temporary array like that.  Instead, have the caller pass in a pointer to an array and then write into it.
2. Similar to the return type, the parameter cannot be `char` if you intend to take a string.  It should be `char*` or `const char*`.