# Display rows where password not in md5 format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, md5

How can I display all the rows in a table where password is not in MD5 format?

I have a table in which some passwords are entered in MD5 format and some are not !!! I want to display all the rows where password is not in MD5 format how can i do that?

I know that the data was inserted with:

```
 MD5('".$password."')
```

How can I retrieve the rows where password is not in MD5 format?

Comment: MD5 is as secure as plaintext these days... Use something stronger (`password_hash`, `password_verify`)

Comment: do you have any limitation in password? like max 15.

Comment: Have you tried with the length? MD5 hashed fields will have a fixed length.

Comment: Don't use md5 for password hashing, it's not secure. See these Q/A, [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6774345/5517143](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6774345/5517143) and [http://security.stackexchange.com/q/19906](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/19906). Always perform [salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on raw password before inserting it into the table.

Comment: I hope you're updating to something better like [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) format. Pro tip: You can reset a user's password when they login to use the updated algorithm if you can verify their existing hash matches.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `password` NOT REGEXP '^[a-f0-9]{32}$'
```

Where `table` is your table name.